# extract multiple two consecutive letters from a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings that contain some US state abbreviation. I want to extract all of them. For example:

```
s='United States WA;United States;Mexico;United States OR;United States PA'
```

My desired output:

```
'WA;OR;PA'
```

I also want the solution to be flexible. The number of states abbreviation present varies. For example, the string can be

```
s='United States WA;United States PA'
```

I want the output to be:

```
'WA;PA'
```

Comment: `[A-Z]{2};{0,1}` could work i think

Comment: Do you want to have `;` in the parsing as well as the output?  e.g.: with "WA. CA.  MO; RE; GE; XZ"  is the output "WA;CA;MO;RE;GE;XZ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess,

```
\b[A-Z]{2}(?:;|$)
```

might simply cover that.

```
import re

s = '''United States WA;United States;Mexico;United States OR;United States PA'''

out = ''
for i in re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{2}(?:;|$)', s):
    out += i

print(out)
```

#### Output

```
WA;OR;PA
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JPyi2F/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/JPyi2F/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

#### Method 2

We can also write those 50 States in a non-capturing group using alternation, such as with:

```
\b(?:AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)(?:;|$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OXRiwL/1/)

and simplify that to:

```
\b(?:A[LKZR]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|FL|GA|HI|I[DLNA]|K[SY]|LA|M[EDAINSOT]|N[EVHJMYCD]|O[HKR]|PA|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|VT|VA|W[AVIY])(?:;|$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/bkkl2f/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s='United States WA;United States;Mexico;United States OR;United States PA'
new_s = re.findall('(?<=\s)\w{2}(?=;)|(?<=\s)\w{2}(?=$)', s)
```

Output:

```
['WA', 'OR', 'PA']
```

Answer (score 1):

behind the two characters you expect a space, and ahead of the two characters you expect either ';' or the end of line

transalating the english description to regex directly yields

```
pat = '(?<=\s)\w{2}(?=;|$)'
re.findall(pat, s) 
# gives me
['WA', 'OR', 'PA']
```

Then join them with ';' to get the desired result:

```
';'.join(re.findall(pat, s))
# outputs:
'WA;OR;PA'
```